# npm run build and serve -s build gives a white/blank screen

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react app that works perfectly fine when npm run start is used. When I use npm run build and serve -s build, the browser gives a white screen

The below is my App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

// Components
import TransferFunds from "./TransferFunds";
import AdminTest from "./AdminTest";
import TransferFundsToPool from "./TransferFundsToPool";

// CSS
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [ipAddress, setIpAddress] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIpAddress = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
        setIpAddress(response.data.ip);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching IP address:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchIpAddress();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar">
          <div className="logo">Hopabot HOPTOKN</div>
          <ul className="nav-links">
            <div className="menu">
              <li>
                <a href="/">Transfer Funds</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/TransferFundsToPool">Transfer Funds to Pool</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/AdminTest">Audit</a>
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<TransferFunds />} />
          <Route
            path="/TransferFundsToPool"
            element={<TransferFundsToPool />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/AdminTest"
            element={<AdminTest ipAddress={ipAddress} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And below is my index.html of the public folder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/Logo.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/Logo.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>HOPTOKN</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried every other solution from all different stack overflow's threads. I have tried adding basename in my BrowserReact property and also tried adding homepage property in the package.json file but it still does not work

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be related to the use of anchor tags (`<a>`) for navigation in your `App.js`. When you use anchor tags with the `href` attribute, the browser performs a full-page refresh, and this can interfere with the client-side routing provided by React Router.

To fix this issue, you should use `Link` components from `react-router-dom`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

// Components
import TransferFunds from "./TransferFunds";
import AdminTest from "./AdminTest";
import TransferFundsToPool from "./TransferFundsToPool";

// CSS
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [ipAddress, setIpAddress] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchIpAddress = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
        setIpAddress(response.data.ip);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching IP address:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchIpAddress();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar">
          <div className="logo">Hopabot HOPTOKN</div>
          <ul className="nav-links">
            <div className="menu">
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Transfer Funds</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/TransferFundsToPool">Transfer Funds to Pool</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/AdminTest">Audit</Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<TransferFunds />} />
          <Route
            path="/TransferFundsToPool"
            element={<TransferFundsToPool />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/AdminTest"
            element={<AdminTest ipAddress={ipAddress} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried your fix but now it throws this error

The above error occurred in the <Link> component:

    at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55541:7)
    at li
    at div
    at ul
    at nav
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:506:84)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Comment: so now even npm run start throws this error along with multiple others. one relating to basename as well

Comment: I can't see  localhost:3000

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: you have provided links (localhost:3000/static/js)
localhost link we cant access / seen

so write errors text

Comment: but i don't think that should matter anyways since changing a tag with a link tag should should throw any errors